# Can not reference other .net core project from unit test project

Tags: unit-testing, .net-core, xunit

I am trying to use xunit to unit test a project I have. I have created a new .Net core class Library project and referenced the other project, but the classes I want do not show up.

This is the project.json file in the test project(I know there is no xunit yet)
[image: This is the project.json file in the test project(I know there is no xunit yet)]

Resharper knows it is there, but when I press the option nothing happens.
[image: Resharper knows it is there, but when I press the option nothing happens.]

UPDATE: Project.Json for WeatherMob

[image]

Comment: The time of .NET Core in VS2015 has passed. Move to VS2017 and you will see it's super easy.

Answer (score 0):

You need to reference your main project in your test projects project dependencies.

```
"dependencies" : {
  "NETStandard.Library" : "1.6.0",
  "WeatherMob": "1.0.0-*"
}
```

Also this will only work if the directory structure is correct.  Meaning the WeatherMob and Test project need to be in the same folder.

```
  /src
    --WeatherMob
    --WeatherMobTests
```

Comment: I get this error when I add the reference  
"One or more projects are incompatible with .NETStandard,Version=v1.6.
    One or more packages are incompatible with .NETStandard,Version=v1.6."

Comment: WeatherMob is a .net 4.5 project? Or a .net core?

Comment: .net Core project

Comment: Can you post the project.json for WeatherMob? Also it might be good to ensure all your nuget packages are at the latest.  Sometimes an old package can cause this error.

Comment: I went ahead and did it.

Comment: NETStandard1.6 most libraries are at 1.1.0 I think if you update this project that would fix the compatibility error.

Comment: Isn't that a downgrade?

Comment: No Sorry I mean like Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc is at 1.1.0.  If you're using VS 2015 you can right click on references and click on Manage Nuget Packages and then go to the updates tab.  It should list all available updates there.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132796/discussion-between-woot-and-sepehr-sobhani).